# MFTF waitForElementVisible element does not found the image

Tags: magento2, mftf

I am facing issue with MFTF tests in finding the image using the below selector:

```
//*[@class='product media']//img[contains(@src, '{{filename}}')]
```

I can see the image is present with the name "magento-logo" but still MFTF doesn't seem to catch it.

Any idea why I am not getting this image via MFTF. I can see in the HTML the image is present.

Please help.